# Complete metric space question

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I am stuck on this question. I think that the answer for both (i) and (ii) should be the same, since alpha is continuous on $[0,1]$, so bounded.

[image]

Comment: @pjs36 oops I am referring to (i) and (ii), I will edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both complete. (i) is a standard exercise, and (ii) follows from (i), since $$\inf |\alpha|  ‖ f - g ‖_∞ ≤ \text{d}_\alpha (f,g) ≤ \sup |\alpha| ‖f-g‖_∞ $$
where $\sup|\alpha|,\inf|\alpha|>0$ by continuity on a compact interval.
So a $\text{d}_\alpha$-Cauchy sequence $f_n$ will converge to some continuous function $f$ in $∞$ norm and hence also wrt the $\text{d}_\alpha$ metric.

Comment: Thank you! but is the answer for (i) that it is complete?

Comment: @lkjhgfdsa Yes, my answer kind of assumes you know that (i) is complete. I will edit the answer.